# What is the effective way to get the Min value but greater than 0 in the list?

Tags: c#, list, linq

```
List <decimal> list = new List<decimal>() {5,4,2,1,0 };
```

The `list.Min()` does not works as it gives me `0`.

Should I make it like `list.Contains(0)` and then *remove* it? Then, just use the `.Min()`.

Comment: `var result = list.Where(item => item > 0).Min();`

Answer (score 5):

Try `Where` in *Linq* in order to filter out values, and finally `Min`:

```
 List <decimal> list = new List<decimal>() {
   5, 4, 2, 1, 0 
 };

 // 1
 var result = list
   .Where(item => item > 0) // Only positive numbers
   .Min();                  // Min among positive numbers only
```